# Not able to pay with Paypal test account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am not able to test payament on paypal sandbox site with existing test accounts.
I came to know that there is revamp in paypal sandbox site. So I created 2 new test accounts , one for business and one for personal. Then I updated my business email id in code but again same problem. On paypal payment page login with personal account throws error saying invalid email/password.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the page you are trying to log into is for the actual sandbox and not the live site.  You would receive this error if your application is pointing towards the live site instead of the sandbox.  If you are on the sandbox, you should see a URL similar to:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com......
```